# Exclude comments from RSS

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice to be able to have an RSS feed that only included questions I ask and answers. This would allow me to share my Stack Overflow activity on other sites without having the noise generated by comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to your profile.
2. Then go to the **Recent** tab.
3. Click on the **RSS** feed for that page.

And then parse out those with the following node:

```
<title type="text">Comment by ...</title>
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: How would I do that? Yahoo pipes (heard of it but never used it)?

Comment: You could Yahoo! Pipe it, just grab the feed, filter out any of the items that contain the title node with "Comment by" and you should be set.

Comment: Yahoo pipes seems to only include the titles not the content in the RSS

Comment: Okay, well, time to play around with some Pipes then...

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/44481/yahoo-pipes-removes-rss-summary

Comment: Good thing it works for you now.